# How to build a ViewPager to slide large images?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I´m trying to use a **ViewPager** to slide a group of images using a **FragmentPagerAdapter**. So each instance of my fragment will show a single image.

I will describe below my understanding of how to do it:

Inside my Adapter, i have this method to pick the correct Fragment:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return FirstImageFragment.newInstance(mImages[0]);
    case 1:
        return MiddleImageFragment.newInstance(mImages[1]);
    case 2:
        return LastImageFragment.newInstance(mImages[2]);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now in my fragment i should implement the static method **newInstance()** to somehow save the image, which will be obtained in **onCreate()** when the fragment is instantiated by Android.

According to what i have read in other answers, the only two ways to pass that image inside the fragment are:

1. saving it into a bundle in **newInstance()** (`bundle.putParcelable("image", image)`)
2. save the image in a private file within a media folder to retrieve it later.

My questions are:

- Is the first method always possible? (considering that the image could be very large. I read that there is a 1MB cap on bundles)
- Isn´t it the second method very inefficient if we are dealing with large images? Do i need to save in the internal memory each image (using different fileNames) just to be retrieved later each of them by **onCreate()**?
- Isn´t it possible to just pass a URI or some kind of unique id/string of the image which i have in a List in my adapter?

Comment: don't you just need to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) and it solves all your problems?

Comment: thanks for that. I´m learning Android so i guess i´d like to know how to do it manually instead of using a 3rd party library

Comment: Then I think the best bet is to read the source code of Picasso 1.x: https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/7ca6b211c392b662350d1aa67b03b0c5e6b9579a/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso